MATLAB coding | rescale the curves into sigle curve
I have the following image which contains three curves, I want to rescale in such way that into a single curve by manipulating the "Z" value with a common factor

The expected results similar to the following image


Why would you do that?  The curves will no longer accurately reflect the data.  You can certainly subtract a constant from the Y values (or multiply by a constant) to bring them closer together, but that seems like it will pollute the data.

Plot the ratio of f(z=0.6)/f(z=04) and f(z=0.4)/f(z=0.2) first to see how closely they can be represented by a constant scaling factor, What you propose to do will be misleading to anyone else looking at the graph. I can see no merit in it at all. If you really do want this then rescale the other two graphs by alpha = f(z=0.2,200)/f(z, 200).

This feels more like a data science question of finding a single curve that 'captures' the three curves using 'scaled' factors, rather than specifically a MATLAB coding problem.

actually the data will collapse together to represent in a simplified form. If "y" axis replaced by "y * z^0.16", the curves will nearly closer together. Tim Roberts, Martin brown and Tony Mathew thanks for your valuable suggestions.
